# How to draw er diagram using wireframes?

Tags: database, database-design, erd

I am designing database er diagram. Can some one help me to design a database schema for event management website?

Comment: ER Diagrams require some form of an english description.  If people designing databases were just like "Im going to design something with no information" we would have a world of redundant and possibly unnecessary databases

Comment: What entities do you need etc